# Access Object that was passed in a WinForm class from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class on a form (user dashboard) which displays user information based on what was passed to it.
I could successfully get the firstaname and lastname and other info of the user. But the issue now is that, I have a button which is on another class, I want to gain access to the object that was successfully passed to the user dashboard.
So, far here is the code which I could successfully passed the user object and use it

```
public partial class UserDashboard : Form
{
        public user user;
        private dbModel db;
        public UserDashboard(user user)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.user = user;
            db = new dbModel();
            LoadUser(user);
        }
        public void LoadUser(user p)
        {
            Color c = lbluserDisplayName.ForeColor = GetLabelForeColor(p);
            if (c == null)
                lbluserDisplayName.Text = user.lastname.ToUpper() + " " + user.firstname;
            else if (c == Color.Red)
                lbluserDisplayName.Text = user.lastname.ToUpper() + " " + user.firstname;
            else
                lbluserDisplayName.Text = user.lastname.ToUpper() + " " + user.firstname;
            lblUserAddress.Text = user.street_address;
            lblUserEmail.Text = "E: " + user.email;
            lblUserHome.Text = "T: " + user.mobile;
            lblUserTelephone.Text = "H: " + user.phone;

        }
}
```

I tried to return the object on this same class that was passed here so that I could use it on another class

```
        public user Testing(user user)
        {
            return this.user = user;
        }
```

Here is the other class where the button is located at which I need to gain access to based on the user that was passed to the userDashboard. But when I test the object, it has no data in it.

```
public partial class StartPage : Form
{
    public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
user u;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   user u = udash.Testing(u);
   if (u == null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Empty data");
    }else
     MessageBox.Show(u.firstname);

 }
```

Please, what are my not getting right to get access to this object based on what was passed unto the first class??
Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I suppose udash is an instance of your first form. But you are probaby using Testing elewhere too. In StartPage however your u is null, which overwrites the value in udash. Better implement a property of type User in UserDashboard and use it directly. Beware to check if udash is a living object (depends on how you handle forms). On the other hand you can create a static class for messaging and object exchange

Answer (score 0):

The issue with you code is that you are wiping your forms `user` variable that you passed into your form.

In your "Testing" method the code is:

```
public user Testing(user user)
{
    return this.user = user;
}
```

This is updating the local user variable in your form with what you're passing in!

If you break it down it's doing this:

```
this.user = user;
return(this.user)
```

Looking at the form you're calling this from shows:

user u;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   user u = udash.Testing(u);
   if (u == null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Empty data");
    }else
     MessageBox.Show(u.firstname);

 }
```

You define the variable `user u` then you call `user u = udash.Testing(u)` which passes in your `u` variable, which then overwrites the form `user` variable and finally returns what you passed in when you called `Testing`.

At no point do you instantiate the `u` variable so you pass in NULL, overwrite the form variable with NULL then return NULL to your calling form.

If we replace variable names with what the contents are we see:

```
user u = null
udash.Testing(null)
this.user = null
return null;
```

Here's what your Testing method should look like:

```
public user Testing()
{
    return(this.user);
}
```

This way when you call `Testing` you are returning `this.user` that you passed in when you instantiated your form.

You should clean up your `user` variable and turn it into a public property:

```
public user User { get; set; }
```

Then you can access what you've passed in with:

user myuser = myForm.User;

This saves you having to go through the `Testing` method.